# How to open IntelliJ with an extern tool and setting up the dependecies permanantly?

Tags: intellij-idea, module, dependencies, extern, temporary-files

Im working with an enterprise "low-code"-tool to build applications for our Company.
Some parts can be written in Java and other languages. It´s possible to use external tools for coding stuff. I chose IntelliJ for Java stuff. My problem now is, that it just opens a temporary file in IntelliJ so i´m forced to reconfigure my dependencies every time i`m saving the work/reopen intelliJ.
Is there a proper way to handle that? I'm not sure, what i´m searching for. Is IntelliJ the right choice?

Comment: Could you please provide more details? What do you mean by saying temporary file and reconfigure dependencies?

Comment: The tool im using, just provides a "code snipped" to an external editor (in my case intellij) as a short living file. Every time i reopen via the tool, im forced to set up the library in intellij. There is no project structure.